# Collada files in remote_lab

Tags: collada

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm trying to generate DAE files (with Wings3D) but I have problems to show the generated files into remote_lab:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'diffuseMap' of undefined colladamodel.js:490

I'm not sure about what I'm doing worse or what I'm not doing. So, anyone knows the correct form to generate collada files for remote_lab?

Cheers,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10596/collada-files-in-remote_lab/) by [marodga](https://answers.ros.org/users/833/marodga/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-07-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just in case anyone searching here wants to know the answer to this question please refer to this link which has more discussion and example files: http://groups.google.com/group/pr2-remote-lab/browse_thread/thread/8edf8419fde746af

---

Originally posted by [Sarah Osentoski](https://answers.ros.org/users/701/sarah-osentoski/) with karma: 136 on 2011-09-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0